# Impossible to authenticate : No JSON input found

Tags: java, json, scala, google-translate

I have to translate text from one language to another. I am using *Google translation API*. 
However, I can't get authentication to work. I want to provide authentication information through code, I DO NOT want to authenticate automatically with globals variables (I still wonder how that's a good idea).

Though there is a simple method to set the API key, there is no method to specify the credential in a simple way. So I decided to authenticate with JSON, obtained when creating a service key.

```
{
"type": "service_account",
"project_id": "toto",
"private_key_id": "tata",
"private_key": "titi",
"client_email": "tete",
"client_id": "tutu",
"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/toto"
}
```

Then, in the *scala* code:

```
 val cred = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(JSON_AUTHENTICATION_INPUT_STREAM)
 TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(cred)
```

And, of course, I get the following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no JSON input found
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:125)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:49)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.startParsing(JsonParser.java:223)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:380)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:355)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.fromStream(GoogleCredential.java:250)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.fromStream(GoogleCredential.java:226)
at services.TranslatorBaseImpl.<init>(Translator.scala:58)
```

So what? JSON authentication is not working? How can I authenticate through code?

I searched for hours in the official doc but it is useless for such an... advanced... case.

Thanks for your answers, 
Kiss

Answer (score 1):

After more investigation, I succeeded by using *ServiceAccountCredentials* instead of *GoogleCredentials*. 
HOWEVER, even if I can get it to work, this is unacceptable. 
The first is a subclass of the second. The documentation states clearly:

> static  GoogleCredentials  fromStream(InputStream credentialsStream)
>   -> Returns credentials defined by a JSON file stream.

This should work, write? 
Same code, same input, same conf, but the contract is not filled....